# Do Login Alternatives to OpenID Create A New Account?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid

I've always used OpenID to log into StackOverflow.

I see that it's going to be turned off in Feb 2014.

When I try to use an alternate means of login (e.g. Google) it appears to be trying to create a new account.  I don't want that - I want to retain the one I've had for almost five years.

How do I switch my existing accounts to use Google to log in without creating a new account?